# Python: Most efficient way to get two Boolean property frequencies in a list of objects?

Tags: python, list, properties, frequency

I have a User object, with two Boolean properties, like this:

```
class User(object):
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a  # Always a bool
    self.b = b  # Always a bool
```

I have a list of those objects, called `user_list`, and I want to get a frequency count for how many objects have a == True, a == False, b == True, and b == False.

My initial approach was to use collections.Counter, but that requires looping through the list twice:

```
a_count = collections.Counter(u.a for u in user_list)
b_count = collections.Counter(u.b for u in user_list)
print a_count[True], a_count[False], b_count[True], b_count[False]
```

I also thought about just using 4 counters, but that is ugly and doesn't feel pythonic:

```
a_true_count = 0
a_false_count = 0
b_true_count = 0
b_false_count = 0
for u in user_list:
  if u.a:
    a_true_count += 1
  else:
    a_false_count += 1
  if u.b:
    b_true_count += 1
  else:
    a_false_count += 1
print a_true_count, a_false_count, b_true_count, b_false_count
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?  The output can be anything: 4 individual vars, a dict with the values, a list, tuple, whatever, so long as it has those 4 values in it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions.  I ran 100000 timeit runs on all the solutions.  I'll put the results as comments in each of the answers.  The best is Kyle Strand's solution of 2 counters and then subtracting from the list length.  In general, anything that uses collections.Counter() is incredibly slow.  
  
The timeit runs (in seconds) for my two solutions above, for comparison:  
Counter() solution: `5.78`  
loop solution w/ 4 counter vars: `1.16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use two counters, and subtract from the length of `user_list` to find the other two values?

`a_false_count = len(user_list) - a_true_count`

`b_false_count = len(user_list) - b_true_count`

Explicitly looping like that is probably the most efficient solution time-wise, but if you're looking for something a little more succinct code-wise, you might  try `filter()`:

```
a_false_count = len(filter(lambda x: x.a,user_list))
b_false_count = len(filter(lambda x: x.b,user_list))
```

Comment: You could even use `operator.attrgetter('b')` rather than the `lambda`.  That'll probably make it go a little faster.

Comment: The two counters + length subtraction was the fastest solution.  Thanks!  100000 timeit runs gave `0.89`.  For the filter solution the time was `1.62`

Comment: Wow, the filtering was more than 3.5 times faster than the `Counter()` solution described above? That's actually really surprising to me. Thanks for running the numbers and sharing the results!

Comment: @Kyle yeah the main lesson I learned today is to not use Counter() if you care about performance. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think using a `collections.Counter` is the right idea, just do it in a more generic way with a single `Counter` and single loop:

```
from collections import Counter

user_list = [User(True, False), User(False, True), User(True, True), User(False, False)]
user_attr_count = Counter()

for user in user_list:
    user_attr_count['a_%s' % user.a] += 1
    user_attr_count['b_%s' % user.b] += 1

print user_attr_count
# Counter({'b_False': 2, 'a_True': 2, 'b_True': 2, 'a_False': 2})
```

Comment: I agree this was a good idea, but in my 100000 timeit run test it went very slow.  collections.Counter() appears to be very inefficient.  The timeit time was `9.61`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use bit masking:

```
def count(user_list,mask):
    return Counter((u.a<<1 | u.b)&mask for u in user_list)

a=0b10
b=0b01
aANDb=0b11
print count(user_list,aANDb)
```

Comment: I think this solution is a little confusing to read.  Regardless, it only performed a little slow in 100000 timeit runs, at `4.62`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for u in user_list:
    c['a'] += u.a
    c['b'] += u.b

print c['a'], len(user_list) - c['a'], c['b'], len(user_list) - c['b']
```

Comment: I like this solution, but like the other ones that use collections.Counter() it performed pretty slowly.  100000 timeit runs clocked in at `6.83`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that's close to what you had the first time except it only iterates over the list once. It creates two counters, iterates over the list, and for each user it updates each counter. The actual step that does the counting is here:

```
for user in user_list:
    a_count.update([user.a])
    b_count.update([user.b])
```

It uses the update function to update each counter object. You can do this instead of creating the counter in one line using a generator like you did in your first example. The entire code sample is here:

```
import collections

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

user_list = [
    User(True, False),
    User(False, True),
    User(True, True),
    User(False, False)
]

a_count = collections.Counter()
b_count = collections.Counter()

for user in user_list:
    a_count.update([user.a])
    b_count.update([user.b])


print a_count[True], a_count[False], b_count[True], b_count[False]
```

Comment: This might be my favorite solution from a readability standpoint.  It is nice and clean.  Unfortunately, the performance is abysmal.  :)  Something about the combination of the inefficient collections.Counter() and the update() method made it do 100000 timeit runs in `40.68`.

Comment: Weird... What are you using for the input? I tried with the same user list up there, but multiplied by `100,000`, and it only took 3 seconds. That seems reasonable to me since you're building the entire list of size `400,000` elements in memory at one time.

Comment: Ah, I see that you used `timeit` and not the unix `time` utility.  Well, just as a baseline, I used `timeit` to time the code above but with an empty user_list.  It took 33 seconds just for that, so I'm not sure if the update function is really the reason why the code is so slow. As far as I know, the update function is very fast.

Comment: For all of the sample runs, I used a 100 element user list, generated randomly using the code in Nisan's zip solution.  Here's the code I ran (except I shortened the timeit number because ideone maxes out at 5s execution time).  http://ideone.com/vZ2grN

Comment: Well, I tried it out with `100,000` and it did indeed take forever lol.  I tried it again with user_list as a generator instead of a list (change user_list to '( ... stuff ... )' instead of '[ ... stuff ... ]') and timeit returned `0.207654953003`

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) for this stuff:

```
from collections import Counter
# for test, import random:
import random

# define class
class User(object):
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a  # Always a bool
    self.b = b  # Always a bool

# create an arbitrary set
users = [ User( r % 2 == 0, r % 3 == 0 ) for r in (random.randint(0,100) for x in xrange(100)) ]

# and... count
aCounter, bCounter = map(Counter, zip(*((u.a, u.b) for u in users)))
```

**Update:**
`map(sum, zip(*tuples))` is marginally faster than the for-loop on smaller sample sizes, but the for-loop scales much better for larger sample sizes.. The for loop doesn't gain much performance boost from working over a list of tuples as do the other methods. Possibly because it's already pretty optimal.

`collections.Counter` is still very slow.

```
import random
import itertools
import time
from collections import Counter 

# define class
class User(object):
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a  # Always a bool
    self.b = b  # Always a bool

# create an arbitrary sample
users = [ User( r % 2 == 0, r % 3 == 0 ) for r in (random.randint(0,100) for x in xrange(100)) ]
# create a list of tuples of the arbitrary sample
users2 = [ ( u.a,u.b) for u in users ] 

# useful function-timer decorator           
def timer(times=1):
    def outer(fn):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            t0 = time.time()
            for n in xrange(times):
                r = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            dt = time.time() - t0
            print '{} ran {} times in {} seconds with {:f} ops/sec'.format(fn.__name__, times, dt, times/dt)
            return r
        return wrapper
    return outer 

# now create the timeable functions         
n=10000
@timer(times=n)
def time_sum():
    return map(sum, zip(*((u.a, u.b) for u in users)))
@timer(times=n)
def time_counter():
    return map(Counter, zip(*((u.a, u.b) for u in users)))
@timer(times=n)
def time_for():
    a,b=0,0
    for u in users:
        if u.a is True:
            a += 1
        if u.b is True:
            b += 1
    return a,b
@timer(times=n)
def time_itermapzip():
    return list(itertools.imap(sum, itertools.izip(*((u.a, u.b) for u in users))))

@timer(times=n)
def time_sum2():
    return map(sum, zip(*users2))
@timer(times=n)
def time_counter2():
    return map(Counter, zip(*users2))
@timer(times=n)
def time_for2():
    a,b=0,0
    for _a,_b in users2:
        if _a is True:
            a += 1
        if _b is True:
            b += 1
    return a,b
@timer(times=n)
def time_itermapzip2():
    return list(itertools.imap(sum, itertools.izip(*users2))) 

v = time_sum()
v = time_counter()
v = time_for()
v = time_itermapzip()

v = time_sum2()
v= time_counter2()
v = time_for2()
v = time_itermapzip2() 

# time_sum ran 10000 times in 0.446894168854 seconds with 22376.662523 ops/sec
# time_counter ran 10000 times in 1.29836297035 seconds with 7702.006471 ops/sec
# time_for ran 10000 times in 0.267076015472 seconds with 37442.523554 ops/sec
# time_itermapzip ran 10000 times in 0.459508895874 seconds with 21762.364319 ops/sec
# time_sum2 ran 10000 times in 0.174293994904 seconds with 57374.323226 ops/sec
# time_counter2 ran 10000 times in 0.989939928055 seconds with  10101.623055 ops/sec
# time_for2 ran 10000 times in 0.183295965195 seconds with 54556.574605 ops/sec
# time_itermapzip2 ran 10000 times in 0.193426847458 seconds with 51699.131384 ops/sec

print "True a's: {}\t False a's: {}\nTrue b's: {}\t False b's:{}".format(v[0], len(users)-v[0], v[1], len(users)-v[1]) 
# True a's: 53   False a's: 47
# True b's: 31   False b's:69
v
# [53, 31]
```

Same code with sample size of 1000:

```
# time_sum ran 10000 times in 9.30428719521 seconds with 1074.773359 ops/sec
# time_counter ran 10000 times in 16.7009849548 seconds with 598.767080 ops/sec
# time_for ran 10000 times in 2.61371207237 seconds with 3825.976130 ops/sec
# time_itermapzip ran 10000 times in 9.40824103355 seconds with 1062.897939 ops/sec
# time_sum2 ran 10000 times in 5.70988488197 seconds with 1751.348794 ops/sec
# time_counter2 ran 10000 times in 13.4643371105 seconds with 742.702735 ops/sec
# time_for2 ran 10000 times in 2.49017906189 seconds with 4015.775473 ops/sec
# time_itermapzip2 ran 10000 times in 6.10926699638 seconds with 1636.857581 ops/sec
```

Comment: Personally I find zip and map to be a bit hard to read at a quick glance, so I don't use them often.  Like the other ones that use collections.Counter(), though, this one doesn't do that well for performance.  100000 timeit runs clocked in at `6.32`.  If it was rewritten using zip and map but without the Counter it might be faster.

Comment: @Chad Both points are very valid. I suppose if speed was the goal, you wouldn't use object instances in the first place, and would probably also loop using itertools. As for map and zip, in my experience they became easier to read the more I used them, but that's not necessarily generalizable.

Comment: @Chad so I retried map(Counter,..), map(sum,...), for... and itertools.imap(...) on a list of tuples insted of object instances, and 10000 runs on a random set of 100 did 0.17s for map(sum,...) on tuples. The for loop is faster for objects, but sum is faster for tuples. My guess is it has to do with zip being faster on tuples than object attribute access is on objects instances.